# API Gateway Mock Integration Fails with 500

Tags: aws-api-gateway, terraform

I have an API Gateway integration for a method/resource which works when I call it from the API but not when I actually call it:

```
$ aws apigateway test-invoke-method --rest-api-id $REST_API_ID \
    --resource-id $RESOURCE_ID --http-method GET | jq -r .log,.body
```

This works out fine and I get the following output:

```
Tue May 16 17:46:42 UTC 2017 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Tue May 16 17:46:42 UTC 2017 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /status.json
Tue May 16 17:46:42 UTC 2017 : Method request path: {}
Tue May 16 17:46:42 UTC 2017 : Method request query string: {}
Tue May 16 17:46:42 UTC 2017 : Method request headers: {}
Tue May 16 17:46:42 UTC 2017 : Method request body before transformations:
Tue May 16 17:46:42 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response body before transformations:
Tue May 16 17:46:42 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response headers: {}
Tue May 16 17:46:42 UTC 2017 : Method response body after transformations: { "statusCode": 200 }
Tue May 16 17:46:42 UTC 2017 : Method response headers: {Content-Type=application/json}
Tue May 16 17:46:42 UTC 2017 : Successfully completed execution
Tue May 16 17:46:42 UTC 2017 : Method completed with status: 200

{ "statusCode": 200 }
```

However, I cannot access this at my URL, which is `api.naftuli.wtf/v1/status.json`. I have stages defined at `glhf`, `stable`, and `v1`, so by replacing that, you will see different responses. I just simply want a dummy response that returns a 200 JSON blob.

My Terraform for the resources is [here as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/naftulikay/13ab6e3546c416bd24a2e3fb7138de64). Hopefully this fully shows my API Gateway configuration.

If I test invoke this from the CLI or from the web console, I get back what is expected. However, if I curl this from my deployed API at api.naftuli.wtf, I don't get anything nice:

```
$ for stage in glhf stable v1 ; do 
>   url="https://api.naftuli.wtf/${stage}/status.json"
>   echo "${url}:" 
>   curl -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
>     https://api.naftuli.wtf/${stage}/status.json
>   echo -e '\n
> done
https://api.naftuli.wtf/glhf/status.json:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 36
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 16 May 2017 21:41:38 GMT
x-amzn-RequestId: 712ba52b-3a80-11e7-9fec-b79b62d3bf7f
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 da7a5d0ed7f424609000879e43743066.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: hBwlbPCP9n2rlz53I-Qb9KoffHB_FoxUCZUaJYNnU3XhCWuMpQTP1Q==

{"message": "Internal server error"}

https://api.naftuli.wtf/stable/status.json:
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 23
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 16 May 2017 21:41:38 GMT
x-amzn-RequestId: 71561066-3a80-11e7-9b00-6700be628328
x-amzn-ErrorType: ForbiddenException
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 0c146399837c7d36c1f0f9d2636f8cf8.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: ITX765xD8s4sNuOdXaJ2kPvqPo-w_dsQK3Sq_No130FAHxFuoVhO8w==

{"message":"Forbidden"}

https://api.naftuli.wtf/v1/status.json:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 36
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 16 May 2017 21:41:39 GMT
x-amzn-RequestId: 7185fa99-3a80-11e7-a3b1-2f9e659fc361
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 586f1a150b4ba39f3a668b8055d4d5ea.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: dvnOa1s-YlwLSNzBfVyx5tSL6XrjFJM4_fES7MyTofykB3ReU5R1fg==

{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

My understanding of stages were that they were additional path prefixes to the base path under which all API resources were available. If I had a stage called `v1` with a path of `/v1`, I'd expect that an API Gateway resource for `status.json` will be basically mapped under `/v1`, yielding `/v1/status.json`.

I may be misunderstanding how API Gateway base path mappings and stages work, but CloudWatch tells me that the call is at least happening, though failing for some obscure reason:

```
21:41:39(c5be3842-6af4-4725-a34f-d6eea8042d17) Verifying Usage Plan for request: c5be3842-6af4-4725-a34f-d6eea8042d17. API Key: API Stage: tcips69qx2/prod_v1
21:41:39(c5be3842-6af4-4725-a34f-d6eea8042d17) API Key authorized because method 'GET /status.json' does not require API Key. Request will not contribute to throttle or quota limits
21:41:39(c5be3842-6af4-4725-a34f-d6eea8042d17) Usage Plan check succeeded for API Key and API Stage tcips69qx2/prod_v1
21:41:39(c5be3842-6af4-4725-a34f-d6eea8042d17) Starting execution for request: c5be3842-6af4-4725-a34f-d6eea8042d17
21:41:39(c5be3842-6af4-4725-a34f-d6eea8042d17) HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /v1/status.json
21:41:39(c5be3842-6af4-4725-a34f-d6eea8042d17) Execution failed due to configuration error: statusCode should be an integer which defined in request template
21:41:39(c5be3842-6af4-4725-a34f-d6eea8042d17) Method completed with status: 500
```

Apparently *only* traffic across the V1 stage is getting through to CloudWatch logs. I have a misconfiguration somewhere and I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your base path mapping in the custom domain name settings.  If you want api.naftuli.wtf/v1/status.json to work with a single API with the stage name of v1, then you need a base path mapping with an empty base path, and empty stage (since you're specifying it in the invoke path), and mapped to your restApiId.

Comment: @MikeDatAWS I have updated the question and [provided a link to more of my Terraform](https://gist.github.com/naftulikay/13ab6e3546c416bd24a2e3fb7138de64).

Comment: Hi Naftuli Kay. It would be useful documentation to mark one of the answers as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 18):

Can you try and change you request template in the integration request setup to this:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200
}
```

API Gateway looks for the status code to return in the response in your [integration request template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-mock-integration.html#how-to-mock-integration-request-examples). The response is generated by the mapping template in the integration response. I can see from your terraform setup that you are loading the output json file in the integration request template. This is content API Gateway does not expect.

Comment: In my case, I needed to remove the quotations from `statusCode`

Comment: `{ statusCode: 200 }`

Comment: Thank you for this!

This was my issue, I was using cloud formation to deploy my API, and never added the integration request mapping template to the OPTIONS method!

Comment: Removing the quotations from `statusCode` in the Integration Request worked for me as well. This is weird because `"statusCode"` came auto-filled when I created a new API from scratch with Mock Integration Endpoint.

Answer (score 4):

With Mock Integration Amazon API Gateway there are 2 common reasons for 500 Internal Server error.

1. Check the mapping template in Integration Request and ensure that you are passing statusCode as an integer to the MOCK Integration endpoint.

   {
   "statusCode": <Integer_Status_code>
   }

Note: Make sure that status code is passed as integer not string.

Correct : 200      Incorrect : "200"

2. Mock Integrations do not support the binary content. If the API is enabled with bixnary support and has application/json or  */* set as binaryMediaTypes, MOCK Integration endpoints would throw a 500 Internal server error when trying to transform the content.

   A workaround is to update the contentHandling property of the MOCK Integration to CONVERT_TO_TEXT

Read more here :- https://cloudnamaste.com/500-internal-server-error-mock-integration/

Answer (score 3):

For my case, when I deploy the lambda with serverless framework, the OPTIONS returns 200 when called. However, when I configure manually on AWS API Gateway, it returns 500 Internal Server Error.

When I check the execution log of API gateway, it said

```
(ee0a42d9-2cfc-4788-8679-00fbd7938cf1) Method request body before transformations: [Binary Data]
(ee0a42d9-2cfc-4788-8679-00fbd7938cf1) Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request
(ee0a42d9-2cfc-4788-8679-00fbd7938cf1) Gateway response body: 
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

After you create the Resources and OPTIONS methods, select the OPTIONS method then

1. At Method Execution --> Integration Request --> expand the Mapping Templates, choose "When no template matches the request Content-Type header". Add or select "application/json" in the Content-Type. Click the "application/json", and in the Generate template, paste
   `{statusCode: 200}` without any double quote. Note, if the `{"statusCode": 200}` exists but with double quote, remove it to be the same as above. Then Save it
2. At Method Execution --> Integration Response --> expand the 200 response status --> Mapping Template --> Add or select "application/json" in the Content-Type. Make sure that the Generate template box is empty. Then Save it
3. At Method Execution --> Method Response --> expand the 200 response. In Response Headers for 200, add three headers: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Leave the Response Body for 200 to be empty
4. Action --> Enable CORS for the Resource
5. Action --> Deploy API

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two distinct problems with your configuration.

First, one of your three base path mappings doesn't match the way you're trying to invoke your API.  Note that the base paths don't have to be the same as your stage names, but they can be if you desire. Since your base path mappings include base paths and stage names, API Gateway is expecting the invoke path to include a base path mapping and not a stage, so it is interpreting the [glhf stable v1] portion of your path as a base path and looking for the corresponding base path mapping entry to determine the API and stage to use.  This works fine for the v1 and glhf base paths which return 500 (indicating a different problem).  The stable base path (in https://api.naftuli.wtf/stable/status.json) returns a 403 Forbidden because there is no base path of "stable" defined for the domain name api.naftuli.wtf.  The stable stage is mapped to the "latest" base path, so calling https://api.naftuli.wtf/latest/status.json should be the way to call the stable stage.  This doesn't currently work, and I don't know why.  If you tell me what region your running this in, I can look-up the config and do more digging.

The second problem is indicated by the following entry from your CloudWatch logs:

> Execution failed due to configuration error: statusCode should be an integer which defined in request template

Can you check that your integration request template (in the file your reference in "${file("${path.module}/files/status.json")}") contains "statusCode: 200" as a top level attribute.

I also found it surprising that you're using the same file for a request template and a response template.

Comment: Hey @mike-at-aws, what about this from the [AWS docs](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-mock-integration.html): "alternatively you can have a method of the mock integration return the default integration response without defining the integration request mapping template"

Answer (score 1):

Having had the identical errors I found what helped me solve this issue was to delete my OPTIONS request definition in the AWS Console. I then followed the console's "Enable CORS" form which created a new OPTIONS method.

I subsequently ran `terraform plan` and looked at the diff between my OPTIONS defintion and theirs. Given that the AWS Console created OPTIONS method worked I applied the changes.

Using terraform 0.12 or greater makes this possible as the `terraform plan` output detail is more fine grained.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing this in CloudFormation.

It took me a while to get it and the accepted answer here was extremely helpful, but a little vague, so adding some more info.

`Stefano Buliani`'s answer, in CloudFormation YAML, looks like:

```
RequestTemplates:
    application/json: | 
        { statusCode: 200 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a `*/*` related to the binary types

[image]

**Once I removed it**, I got rid of that error and everything started working as expected

Answer (score 0):

What was especially weird here was apparently, the fix was simply to create a deployment using the AWS CLI for each of the stages. Apparently, Terraform was not updating or re-kicking deployments on changes, and so my changes never got out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and eventually figured out that my client was using a different content type than I expected. I had foolishly assumed it would use application/json, but it was some custom json thing. In my setup, API Gateway is logging to cloudwatch, which is where I found the content type it received from the client. Once I updated the content type in the request template of the mock integration, things worked as expected.